# clang++ vs g++ constexpr difference with out of bound reference

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior, constexpr, clang++

I have `constexpr std::array<int, N> v1{0}, v2{0};` which behaves like big integers. So, I write a `multiply` function to find the product of the numbers.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

template <int N>
constexpr array<int, 2 * N> multiply(const array<int, N> &a,
                                     const array<int, N> &b) {
    const int as = N, bs = N, rs = as + bs;
    array<int, rs> result{0};

    __int128_t carry = 0;
    auto pr = begin(result);
    for (int r = 0, lim = min(rs, as + bs - 1); r < lim; ++r) {
        int i = r >= as ? as - 1 : r,           
            j = r - i,
            k = i < bs - j ? i + 1 : bs - j;    // min(i+1, bs-j);
        auto pa = begin(a) + i;
        auto pb = begin(b) + j;
        while (k--) {
            carry += static_cast<__int128_t>(*(pa--)) * (*(pb++));
        }
        *(pr++) = static_cast<int64_t>(carry);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int N = 20;
    constexpr array<int, N> v1{0}, v2{0};
    constexpr array<int, 2 *N> result = multiply<N>(v1, v2);
    return result[1];
}
```

Note that the multiply function is incorrect to make it minimal.

When I compile this code using `clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -O0 example.cc`, I  **erroneously** get:

```
example.cc:30:32: error: constexpr variable 'result' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr array<int, 2 *N> result = multiply<N>(v1, v2);
                               ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
example.cc:20:50: note: cannot refer to element -1 of array of 20 elements in a constant expression
            carry += static_cast<__int128_t>(*(pa--)) * (*(pb++));
                                                 ^
example.cc:30:41: note: in call to 'multiply(v1, v2)'
    constexpr array<int, 2 *N> result = multiply<N>(v1, v2);
                                        ^
1 error generated.
```

**But this compiles correctly with gcc.**

Why I think clang's error is an error:

To verify whether there is an out of bound access I enabled libstdc++'s debug mode and compiled using `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -g -O0 example.cc` and there was no crash which would have happened if there was an out of bound access.

Also under sanitizers (`g++ -fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer`) code ran successfully.

I am curious as to why clang claims out of bound access, while the experiments clearly shows it is not the case.

Comment: why clang++ -std=c++17 -Wall -O0   ?  ..try -O3

Comment: No crash does not mean that the program is valid. UB is just undefined. Anything could happen. (I'm not saying there is UB, I'm just saying that no crash does not mean there is not).

Comment: @super, compiling with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` takes care of the out of bound access and Sanitizers take care of undefined behavior.

Comment: clang isn't complaining about an out-of-bound **access**, it is complaining about creating a pointer that points outside of the array (it doesn't care that you are not dereferencing it).

Comment: @MarcGlisse, if true then there is a big problem because I shouldn't pay for what I didn't do! A warning should be enough but an error is too much!

Comment: "_Some types of UB are simply undetectable by the compiler._ " Well since this function has to run at compile time, the compiler is required to detect everything since UB is not allowed in a compile time context.

Comment: @Timo Sorry, left that comment before spotting the bug here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang is right.  You did not "[**erroneously** get](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59907616/3)" the error.

```
*(pa--)
```

Assuming that `k` is initially set to `i + 1`, prior to the last time the last time this expression is evaluated in the `while` loop, `pa` points to the first element of the array.  `pa--` involves evaluating `pa - 1`, which results in undefined behavior according to [[expr.add]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.add#4): (`i = 0`, `j = 1`)

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the expression `P` points to element `x[i]` of an array object `x` with `n` elements, the expressions `P + J` and `J + P` (where `J` has the value `j`) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i + j]` if `0 ≤ i + j ≤ n`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. **Likewise, the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element `x[i − j]` if `0 ≤ i − j ≤ n`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Now, a constant expression must not evaluate: [[expr.const]/2.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.6)

> an operation that would have undefined behavior as specified in Clauses [intro] through [cpp] of this International Standard

Therefore, `multiply<N>(v1, v2)` is not a constant expression, and a diagnostic is required here.

Of course, this `[-1]` pointer will usually not cause problems unless you dereference it, but it's nonetheless undefined behavior, which prevents it from being a part of a constant expression.  Sanitizers can only diagnose a limited subset of undefined behavior.